# Why does MySQL IN() function work with unknown field

Tags: mysql

Having two tables:

**Customers** with fields CustomerId and AnotherId

**Orders** with fields OrderId and CustomerId

How is it possible that the following query works, even though AnotherId does not exist in the Orders table?

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE (CustomerID, AnotherID) IN (SELECT CustomerID, AnotherID FROM Orders);
```

Comment: If it does not exist in Orders it is considered to be the column from Customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that MySQL is interpreting the `AnotherId` column reference in the subquery as belonging to the `Customers` table.

To confirm this, consider the following version of your query which does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Customers 
WHERE (CustomerID, AnotherID) IN (SELECT o.CustomerID, o.AnotherID FROM Orders o);
```

In this case, it is clear that the subquery is referring to only columns from the `Orders` table, and, since that table has no `AnotherId` column, the query fails.  Here is a demo showing that this version of your query fails:

### Demo